# Animating cell height change of UITableView with sections causes artifacts

Tags: ios, uitableview

I get a white line that animates through collapsed section headers during cell height change animations. Note it only happens when selecting a cell causes the height of the section *above* a collapsed section header to change.

Code here: https://github.com/sketch34/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section

[image]

Very simple setup. Reload rows that are selected:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedRow = indexPath
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedRow], with: .automatic)
}
```

Change cell contents if selected:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: CollapsibleTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? CollapsibleTableViewCell ??
        CollapsibleTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    let item: Item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name

    // *** This line changes cell contents if selected ***
    cell.detailLabel.text = (selectedRow != nil) && indexPath.elementsEqual(selectedRow!) ? item.detail : ""

    return cell
}
```

Besides the artifact in the screenshot I can't see where the white line is coming from in the first place. I've tried:

```
// In my UITableViewHeaderFooterView.
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

// In my UITableViewController.
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none
```

Some more details:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented the estimatedHeightForFowRowAt or heightForRowAt functions?

Comment: Thanks, I've added some details about these to the question. Could these be the issue?